# asp.net 5 (vnext) and entity framework 6

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm working on adding an Entity Framework data context to an ASP.NET 5 class library and I keep getting errors that `System.Data.Entity` is not referenced.

Adding a reference to it only works if the build target is set to `.net 4.5.1`. This doesn't work for `.net core 5`.

I'm using VS 2015 RC and the DNVM version of ASP.NET 5 installed is `1.0.0-beta4`.

Any ideas if this has been moved or why it's not working?

**Edit:** added the `project.json` file

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "description": "",
    "authors": [ "" ],
    "tags": [ "" ],
    "projectUrl": "",
    "licenseUrl": "",

    "dependencies": {
        "EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
        "Microsoft.DataAnnotations": "1.0.0-beta1"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": { }
        "dnxcore50": {
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-22816",
                "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-22816",
                "System.Threading": "4.0.10-beta-22816",
                "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0-beta-22816"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`EntityFramework 6` is not compatible with `ASP.Net core 5`, it's why you have this error.
If you want to use `EF6`, you must untarget `dnxcore50`.

**Edit:** add sample to untarget `'dnxcore50`
Your project.json will be:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "description": "",
    "authors": [ "" ],
    "tags": [ "" ],
    "projectUrl": "",
    "licenseUrl": "",

    "dependencies": {
        "EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
        "Microsoft.DataAnnotations": "1.0.0-beta1"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": { }
        }
    }
}
```

Or, use `EntityFramework 7`
**Edit:** add sample to use `EF7`
Assuming you want to use `SqlServer` and commands to generate migrations, your `project.json` will be:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "description": "",
    "authors": [ "" ],
    "tags": [ "" ],
    "projectUrl": "",
    "licenseUrl": "",

    "dependencies": {
        "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta4",
        "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.DataAnnotations": "1.0.0-beta1"
    },

    "commands": {
         "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": { }
        "dnxcore50": {
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-22816",
                "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-22816",
                "System.Threading": "4.0.10-beta-22816",
                "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0-beta-22816"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: EF7 gave the same error. Any ideas on how to fix that?